# How to find /usr/bin/gedit?

Tags: gedit

I can open gedit using the terminal but I want to be able to open the folder that has gedit, how?

Answer (score 0):

Use whereis to locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command

```
$ whereis gedit
gedit: /usr/bin/gedit /usr/lib/gedit /usr/share/gedit /usr/share/man/man1/gedit.1.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

For search **files** and **directories** use:

```
find / -name gedit
```

Just for searching directories:

```
find / -name gedit -type d
```

Source:
[General Command Manual FIND](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

Other example applying this command **find** ... 
that end with the characters "test":

```
find /home/enduser/ -name "*test"
```

or that begin with the characters"ged":

```
find / -name "ged*"
```

Don´t forget to checkout privileges or permission level when you´re looking for files or directories, sometimes require a Super User.

Hope this helps.